# Tooltip background color gets faded angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using chart.js i am getting difficulty to display my tooltip. Tooltip background color gets faded and user is unable to read text on it. i have tried it by changing background and font color but nothing helps out there.

[image]

Comment: @ZaidIqbal - could you add a fiddle showing the problem? It'll be easier to make the fix on that than trying to replicate the problem first. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `z-index:100;` to your tooltip this will work

Comment: I am using chartJS library. so please specify where in chartjs i need to specify this property

Comment: can you provide your css please

Comment: @ZaidIqbal in you should change it by giving class to that div where tooltip is displayed and add `z-index` value to that class

Comment: it's not about css. I am missing any property of chartjs. That's why i put this question here

Comment: there is no option in `chart,js` for that you have change it from css or refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338141/chart-js-custom-tooltip-option) this will help you