# Chart.js doughnut chart tooltip size?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, chart.js

i'm want to resize tooltips on chart.
I've used global settings but doesn't work. Tooltips on my charts are too small.
[Here is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0lyY.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Chart options
    Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
    Chart.defaults.global.titleFontSize = 20;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [
                "Produkty",
                ""
            ],
            datasets: [
            {
                data: <?=json_encode(array_values($values));?>,
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#2ecc71",
                    "#3498db"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#27ae60",
                    "#2980b9"
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 80
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You might see [Chart JS custom tooltip option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39204408/2026740)

Comment: Works, thanks!
in options just use

 tooltips: 
{

    bodyFontSize: 25

}

Comment: Should be:
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleFontSize = 16;

you forgot the .tooltips :)

Answer (score 19):

You can change the title font size too.

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    titleFontSize: 10,
    bodyFontSize: 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
options: {
     tooltips: { bodyFontSize: 20 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was required to go in the library section

```
{
  ...,
  library: {
    tooltips: {
      ...
    },
  },
  ...
}
```